A mailing in "running" status - possible due to one recipient's incorrect email address: how to unstuck?
It is D10/CiviCRM 5.71.x  A few mailings are still in the "Running" status at 99.35% of the Successful Deliveries according to detailed reports.
Accompanied by repeated log messages. Is there any way to "unstuck" mailings  without messing around the database please?

[info] SMTP Socket Error or failed to set sender error.
Message: Failed to add recipient: xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.co.uk [SMTP: Invalid
response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is
often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please
verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >>
Outbound Email (SMTP). (code: 451, response: Temporary local problem -
please try later)], Code: 10005


I have the same problem. Have you found the solution? Thanks

@masetto Try to remove or fix the broken email address and see if it helps. I think this is how it has been fixed in my case, can't quite recall though.
